# Persist new JPA entity and detach

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

The use case is:

- create a lot of new entities and save them in a single transaction in database

The only efficient solution I could find using JPA/Hibernate was to do the following steps. The reason for this is that hibernate is keeping the entities in the first level cache until the end of transaction.

- create a new entity
- force a quick flush()
- detach the entity

The overhead of doing this are

- you need to inject an entityManager/sessionFactory into your business logic, and manage flush and detach of entities
- you need to force an inefficient flush after each insert

The real expectation would be that JPA or at least Hibernate would expose some kind of functionallity to quickly create an entity and persist it without keep it managed.

Other solutions:

- use JDBC or JdbcTemplate but then you will have to write your own inserts for the entities

So the question is: is there a possibility to persist and detach at the same time or even better persist without becoming managed?

Comment: have you looked into batch inserts? https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/03/18/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/

Comment: You can implement your own `saveAndDetach` method. See [adding custom behaviour to repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories) in the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Stateless Session which does not have a first level cache.
From the docs:

```
 StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
 Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
 ScrollableResults customers = session.getNamedQuery("GetCustomers")
        .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
 while ( customers.next() ) {
     Customer customer = (Customer) customers.get(0);
     customer.updateStuff(...);
     session.update(customer);
 }     
 tx.commit();
 session.close();
```

> In this code example, the Customer instances returned by the query are
>   immediately detached. They are never associated with any persistence
>   context.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html

Comment: unfortunately I need to be inside a transaction, it's all or nothing

Comment: No problem then, how does the above solution prevent you to do so?

Comment: I presume a StatelessSession can't exist inside a transaction

Comment: I don't think it matters, transactions work either way. I have personally used `StatelessSession` for 'lightweight querying' only but the above example is from Hibernate Docs so it should work. 
If you're using Spring's Declarative transactions, `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)` or your custom exception, and all should be good.